# jquery select change get data attribute value for each tr td in The table contains dynamically generated rows

Tags: javascript, php

I've created a table with two rows, with the ability to create additional rows dynamically; the problem I'm having is that I want to make the value of the last cell in any row related to the user's choice from the drop-down list in the first cell in the row.

I have code that works, but it only works on the first row correctly and repeats printing the same value in all next rows, any good suggestion would be appreciated and thank you;

[my problem is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gbbu.png):

[image]

```
<script>
  $('#select_acount').on('change', function() {
  $('.mount').val($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

html code :

```
<td> <select class="form-control select2" id="select_acount"  required>
<option value="">--الحساب--</option>
<?php
  $query = "select * from sah7atmain_acouts WHERE company like '".$multi."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
  if($result) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>   
      <?php echo '<option  value="'.$row['acount_mounte'].'">'.$row['acount_name'].'</option>'?>;
      <?php
    }
  } else{
}
?>
</select></td>
<td> 
<input type="number" name="debtor[]" id="fname"class="form-control quantity arabicNumbers" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69" required> </td>
<td> <input type="number" name="creditor[]" id="james" class="form-control amount arabicNumbers" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69" required> </td>
<td> <input type="text"  name="description[]" class="form-control"  required> </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="mount[]" class="form-control mount"   required> </td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td> <select class="form-control select2"  required>
<option value="">--الحساب--</option>
<?php
$query = "select * from sah7atmain_acouts WHERE company like '".$multi."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
if($result)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>

<?php echo '<option value="'.$row['acount_name'].'">'.$row['acount_name'].'</option>'?>;
<?php
}
} else{
}
?>
</select></td>
<td> <input type="number" name="debtor[]" id="fname"class="form-control quantity arabicNumbers" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69" pattern="[0-9]*"required> </td>
<td> <input type="number" name="creditor[]" id="james" class="form-control amount arabicNumbers" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69" pattern="[0-9]*"required> </td>
<td> <input type="text"  name="description[]" class="form-control"  required> </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="mount[]" class="form-control mount" id="mount" required> </td>
<td> <button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button></td>
```

Comment: Your "HTML" is [tag:php], and irrelevant to your question since JavaScript - that implements the client-side functionality you're implementing - works on the client, and not the server. So please, remove the irrelevant PHP script and instead paste the **relevant** "*[mcve]*" HTML (as received by your browser), CSS and JavaScript. Also, while I tried to tidy up your PHP for readability purposes, I gave up. When you post your relevant code (as asked), please try to ensure it's formatted to be readable by humans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of id use class as you can use 1 id only once in a particular page. so your code would be:

```
$('.select_acount').on('change', function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').find('.mount').val($(this).val());
});
```

closest will find your nearest tr to your select button inside which it will find element with mount class and update value there

Comment: The problem is worse, your code can't even show the value I was getting, unfortunately the code is wrong

Comment: have you added this class `select_acount` to your select dropdown

Comment: I appreciate this, my friend. Thank you. The code is now working successfully. This is credited to you, my friend. I owe you this

Answer (score 1):

```
var priceval = new Array();   //Declaare array to store data 
$('.testp').each(function() { //Function for dynamic class
 priceval.push($(this).val()); //Fetch Values from class elements and put into the priceval array
});
```

Comment: Instead of commenting your explanation, just explain in a few sentence what this solves.